# Validation DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to implement custom validations on an object bound to a datagrid in WPF.

From the exemple of Microsoft : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975(v=vs.110).aspx

If I erase the "Course Id", I got an error with a tooltip from the default logic of the FrameWork.

[image: Default implementation]

Now if I put a custom validation that throw an exeption in the Set method of the model, I got an error at the row level but nothing at the cell level.

[image: Custom error]

```
public int Id
{
    get { return _number; }
    set
    {
        if (_number == value) return;
        if (value < 0)  throw new Exception("Custom validation >= 0");
        _number = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Id");
    }
}
```

The red style is not trigged with a custom exeption and I want it.
Seems that Validation.HasError is not set at the cell level.

Comment: Are you certain that throwing an `Exception` is the correct way to produce an invalid cell?